# 0 documents restored when use mongorestore to get data from agz file

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I downloaded an agz file from an open-source site and i want ro restore the db data to my mongodb.
Firstly i execute the command bellow and I got the data successfully.

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=filename.agz --db filename
```

But not all data were restored.There is no space of my disk so that some data failed to be restored. Then I delete some files to get enough space and run that command again.
But this time the command line shows something like `duplicate id error`. And no new data was added to db.
So I drop the database and run the command bellow:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=filename.agz --nsInclude filename
```

And after more than 10 mins I got this:
[execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vjKx.png)

```
2022-01-07T11:10:01.015+0800    preparing collections to restore from
2022-01-07T11:22:16.628+0800    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

What happend? Where are my data? How can I solve this problem and get whole correct data from the agz file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nsInclude` command
Change code like this and it works:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=filename.agz --nsInclude="*"
```

as the official site says, `--db` has been deprecated and you should use `--nsInclude` instead.
Before restore u`d better ensure there is enough space left in your disk.